# Use of IN clause within a DELETE command - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am browsing through the official [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) to learn about the **DELETE** clause.
This page states

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

I can see from this **WHERE**, **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** is allowed but there is no mention of **IN**

Therefore the following valid command

```
DELETE FROM WHERE column = z OR column = y OR column = x OR column = w
```

However I wrote the following command which execute's fine and does exactly the same as the above but looks better.(possibly executes faster too)

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column IN (z,y,x,w)
```

Am I allowed to do this? I am wondering if maybe it works in this case but other cases would fail?
Also if this is fine should'nt the docs state it?

Comment: `IN` is an operator you can use in `WHERE`. There is no restriction on how complicated a `WHERE` clause is.

Comment: @ypercube I did look for the *WHERE* clause/condition/operator in the mysql docs but could not find it, Do you know what "Type" *WHERE* is? Or even better a link to the *WHERE* docs. Thanks!

Comment: The `DELETE` page you link to, has this: *"**where_condition** is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be deleted. It is specified as described in [Section 13.2.8, “SELECT Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)."*

Comment: @ypercube Yes I saw that, but it does not describe how to use the *WHERE* condition and its allowed parameters etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use `IN()` in the `WHERE` clause of a `DELETE` statement.

There is no "`IN` clause" -- `IN()` is just a *comparison operator,* perhaps slightly disguised as something more sophisticated.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

To illustrate what `IN()` is really doing, consider these examples in isolation.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 IN (2,3,4); -- should be false
+--------------+
| 1 IN (2,3,4) |
+--------------+
|            0 | -- is indeed false
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 1 IN (2,1,4); -- should be true
+--------------+
| 1 IN (2,1,4) |
+--------------+
|            1 | -- is indeed true
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

...and, as @ypercube has pointed out, the "`where_condition` is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be deleted".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any criteria you can do in a regular select statement can be done in an update, delete, or insert statement.